# Eclipse offline Extensions install in an almost completely closed environment (proxy)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

**Initial position:**

Currently I'm at a customer's site who has completely locked up his system (VM), and through a proxy blocks nearly everything, including the connections to download the extensions of Eclipse.

[image]

In the Eclipse marketplace you can find the download links, but they are of no use to me. Since the proxy locks everything out.

[image]

If you use the download link, you will get to this page, which ONLY refers to the integration in Eclipse via the web. This is currently not possible for me!

A reference to the M2E version only leads to the page mentioned above.

https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

The customer only allows Eclipse no other programs.

It is unbelievable ^^

Is there a way to install offline extensions in Eclipse like Visual Studio code?

What I need is a Maven/Java based version, including Jenkins integration.

I currently used a portable version of Eclipse from the points already described. Yes, the download of complete versions is possible and not blocked, just the integration of plugins and extensions.

Comment: This is decided on a per-project basis, so there's not going to be a single answer for this question. Some projects make their update sites downloadable as zip files, M2E apparently does not. In this case you might be able to mirror the directory locally, use that, and open a bug report asking them to make zip files available.

Comment: Since the customer's VM for extreme employees is complete and almost complete, only parts of it can be accessed. A release is not possible and cannot be requested. Reason: safe is safe ;)

As an external user you are without rights :)

Comment: You can [download/mirror such a p2 repository via the p2 director](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_mirror.html) and use it in _Help > Install New Software..._. But it is probably easier to install it from a (copied) Eclipse installation that contains it via _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation_.

Comment: If you can't or don't want to transfer files from home (see my last comment), you might create a GitHub repository with an action to mirror an update site. Then you could edit and commit the update site URL using GitHub Web interface, and after a delay, the mirrored website would be ready for download. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: If you're allowed to download complete versions, why not simply download https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-06/R/eclipse-java-2020-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip ? That will contain M2E and Jenkins integration i believe.